# Cheat at Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock

Tags: code-golf, string, game

When playing Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock, your [robot reflexes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qb5UIPeFClM) let you see your opponent's throw before they make it. You just need to choose a throw that beats theirs, in as few bytes as possible of course.

There's always two winning throws, and either one will work.

[image: RPSLS throws diagram]

```
Input    -> Possible outputs
------------------------------
Rock     -> Spock or Paper
Spock    -> Paper or Lizard
Paper    -> Lizard or Scissors
Lizard   -> Scissors or Rock
Scissors -> Rock or Spock
```

Take a string as input, and output one of the strings that beats it. Strings must be exactly as given, with capitalization. List of characters may substitute for strings.

Comment: It's a pity that the two hands that start with `S` have no outputs in common...

Comment: How about leading or trailing whitespace?

Comment: @Bubbler Nope, sorry.

Comment: @JoKing Hardly! Necessity is the mother of invention, and your solution is pretty clever.

Comment: `V` for "Vulcan" would fix the overloaded `S`!

Comment: @JoKing: The *second* letters of the possible inputs are distinct, though.  Possibly useful.

Comment: @JoKing The two hands that *end* in <code>k</code> do, though.

Answer (score 67):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>36</s> 30 bytes

```perl6
{<Spock Lizard Rock>[.comb%4]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY2xDsIgFEV3vuItWh0ek3HSfoGDaUfjgEgNsQ0EulTjt@ODRxnIS86953oTxmOaFtgOcIb0PfXe6Tdc7EeFJ3R0tzep3fTYHO6/FNUCkpKDC/Ays4x@tPOuwWafchSvypuAvbYxuhCRLViUQuQE5Ict8ApZSkOUv6I6TWz1iPXIuKtFltYwO9cU0ZwSPMKQF4hw4w8)

Gets each output based on the length of the input modulo 4. I think this is probably the optimal strategy.

Answer (score 21):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 28 bytes

```perl
$_=/k/?Paper:/i/?Rock:Lizard
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lY/W98@ILEgtchKP1PfPig/OdvKJ7MqsSjl/38Qhyu4AESCVXBBJLiCkzOLi/OLiv/lF5Rk5ucV/9ctyAEA)

Tried @JoKing's length mod 4 method, but this turned out to be even shorter.

Comment: At first glance this looked like sed for me.

Comment: @val, Perl was inspired by `sed` and `awk`

Comment: +1, pretty sure this is optimal unless you can combine output words somehow.

Answer (score 13):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 39 bytes

Shorter `md5` variants by [Christoph](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29637/christoph) and [Benoit Esnard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38454/benoit-esnard).

```php
<?=[Lizard,Spock,Rock][md5(y.$argn)%3];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt422iezKrEoRSe4ID85WycISMRG56aYalTqqSQWpedpqhrHWv9PTc7IV1CKyVOy/g9SwQVWzBWQWJBaxAXRzxWcnFlcnF9U/C@/oCQzP6/4v64bAA)

```php
<?=[Spock,Rock,Lizard][md5($argn.m)%7];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42OrggPzlbJwhE@GRWJRalxEbnpphqqCQWpefp5Wqqmsda/09NzshXUIrJU7L@D1LIBdbDFZBYkFrEBdHEFZycWVycX1T8L7@gJDM/r/i/rhsA)

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 40 bytes

```php
<?=[Rock,Spock,Lizard][md5($argn)[5]%3];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42Oig/OVsnuABE@mRWJRalxEbnpphqqCQWpedpRpvGqhrHWv9PTc7IV1CKyVOy/g9SzwVWzxWQWJBaxAXRxRWcnFlcnF9U/C@/oCQzP6/4v64bAA)

Takes sixth character of md5 of input, which gives unique number of `1` for "Rock" and "Scissors", unique number of `2` for "Spock" and "Paper" and unique number of `9` for "Lizard". A mod 3 on those numbers and we have `0` or `1` or `2` indexes.

```
| Input    | MD5                              | 6th char | %3 | Output |
|----------|----------------------------------|----------|----|--------|
| Rock     | 4cfbb125e9878528bab91d12421134d8 |        1 |  1 | Spock  |
| Spock    | 5769c28299713c949cd59d5469e40ace |        2 |  2 | Lizard |
| Paper    | d0a662a5235ecde30739fe50cf0de830 |        2 |  2 | Lizard |
| Lizard   | 2f7569e00c4d97aef5f2c2b3a4d2213f |        9 |  0 | Rock   |
| Scissors | 28204140cee6e34a9843b64e5a490b08 |        1 |  1 | Spock  |
```

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 40 bytes

Alternative 40 bytes, port of [Jo King's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195084).

```php
<?=[Spock,Lizard,Rock][strlen($argn)%4];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42OrggPzlbxyezKrEoRScIyI6NLi4pyknN01BJLErP01Q1ibX@n5qcka@gFJOnZP0fpIQLrIkrILEgtYgLopUrODmzuDi/qPhffkFJZn5e8X9dNwA)

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 41 bytes

This is based on [79037662's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195115).

```php
<?=[Lizard,Rock,Paper][ord($argn[-1])%3];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt422iezKrEoRScoPzlbJyCxILUoNjq/KEVDJbEoPS9a1zBWU9U41vp/anJGvoJSTJ6S9X@QSq7gAhAJVs8FMYErODmzuDi/qPhffkFJZn5e8X9dNwA)

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/) (7.4), 42 bytes

Uses fifth and sixth characters of input to get one of 0, 1 or 2.

```php
fn($s)=>[Rock,Lizard,Paper][!$s[5]+!$s[4]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwMWlkmb7Py1PQ6VY09YuOig/OVvHJ7MqsShFJyCxILUoNlpRpTjaNFYbRJnExv635uJKTc7IV1BJ01AHqVbXVNBTUIrJU7JGiAcX4JAAG4lNAmIlVrOSM4uL84uKEXL/AQ)

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 43 bytes

Uses [CRC32](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php) of input and mod to get 0, 1 or 2.

```php
<?=[Rock,Lizard,Paper][crc32($argn)%866%3];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42Oig/OVvHJ7MqsShFJyCxILUoNjq5KNnYSEMlsSg9T1PVwsxM1TjW@n9qcka@glJMnpL1f5AWruACEAnWwQXRzhWcnFlcnF9U/C@/oCQzP6/4v64bAA)

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 43 bytes

Uses second to the last character of input ("Rock" and "Spock" = "c", "Paper" = "e", "Lizard" and "Scissors" = "r").

```php
<?=[c=>Paper,e=>Lizard,r=>Rock][$argn[-2]];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42OtnWLiCxILVIJ9XWziezKrEoRafI1i4oPzk7NlolsSg9L1rXKDbW@n9qcka@glJMnpL1f5AkV3ABiARr5YLo4wpOziwuzi8q/pdfUJKZn1f8X9cNAA)

Comment: 39 by adding some pepper: `<?=[Lizard,Spock,Rock][md5(y.$argn)%3];`.

Comment: 39 bytes: `<?=[Spock,Rock,Lizard][md5($argn.m)%7];` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42OrggPzlbJwhE@GRWJRalxEbnpphqqCQWpefp5Wqqmsda/09NzshXUIrJU7L@D1LIBdbDFZBYkFrEBdHEFZycWVycX1T8L7@gJDM/r/i/rhsA "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: @BenoitEsnard ha beat you by 5 seconds! :)

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 28 bytes

```apl
'Spock' 'Lizard' 'Rock'⊃⍨4|≢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/9WDC/KTs9UV1H0yqxKLUoCMIBD/UVfzo94VJjWPOhf9TwMqfNTbB9HT1XxovfGjtolAXnCQM5AM8fAM/p8G1cYFZEAMBLECEgtSi8AsqOFg6eTM4uL8omJ1rke9c0GaFEBA104BrE8hv0gBrA0kCxGByIIFQbIQo0DSECGINEQUJA8zH6QCKgoxHioOUgOyFmwBTAwoHwS1HWwpAA)

Uses the simple strategy based on input length modulo 4 (idea from [Jo King's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195084/78410)). `⎕IO←0`.

---

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 34 bytes

```apl
'Lizard' 'Rock' 'Paper'⊃⍨'Xbj'⍸2∘⊃
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X90nsyqxKEVdQT0oPzkbSAUkFqQWqT/qan7Uu0I9IilL/VHvDqNHHTOAIv/THrVNeNTb96hvqqc/kH9ovfGjtolAXnCQM5AM8fAM/p8GNYgLyAgugLEghoJYUOvA0smZxcX5RcXqXI9654I0KYCArp0CWJ9CfpECWBtIFiICkQULgmQhRoGkIUIQaYgoSB5mPkgFVBRiPFQcpAZkLdgCmBhQPghqO9hSAA)

Uses the shortest choice for all cases. `⎕IO←1`.

#### How it works

```apl
'Lizard' 'Rock' 'Paper'⊃⍨'Xbj'⍸2∘⊃
2∘⊃     Take the second character
'Xbj'⍸  Classify it by intervals:
        'X'≤c<'b': 1
        'b'≤c<'j': 2
        'j'≤c    : 3
...⊃⍨   Give the nth string
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```
Lị“ŀ¡ḋ¤:1KỌ»Ḳ¤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/n4e7uRw1zjjYcWvhwR/ehJVaG3g939xza/XDHpkNL/gNlgvKTs4FUQGJBahGQDk7OLC7OLyoGMn0yqxKLUkBiBWA1cw9tPbrncPujpjWR/wE)

-2 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan and Nick Kennedy both independently coming up with splitting on spaces instead of using a list literal.

A translation of Jo King's Perl 6 solution, using Jelly's compressed strings and modular indexing.

```
 ị                The element of
  “ŀ¡ḋ¤:1KỌ»      "Lizard Rock  Spock"
            Ḳ¤    split on spaces
 ị                at (1-based) index
L                 length of the input
  “ŀ¡ḋ¤:1KỌ»Ḳ¤    mod 4.
```

Comment: Using split-at-spaces saves two bytes: `“ŀ¡ḋ¤:1KỌ»Ḳị@L` or `Lị“ŀ¡ḋ¤:1KỌ»Ḳ¤`

Comment: I was about to post an almost identical comment: https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/n4e7uRw1zjjYcWvhwR/ehJVaG3g939xza/XDHpkNL/gNlgvKTs4FUQGJBahGQDk7OLC7OLyoGMn0yqxKLUkBiBWA1cw9tPbrncPujpjWR/wE

Comment: That's 29 bytes in UTF-8, not 14

Comment: Am I missing something? It doesn't take input of the required form or produce output of the required form.

Comment: [It's not in UTF-8](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page), and [it does input and output just fine if you take the footer out, and run it one case at a time](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9qZWxsef//TOG7i@KAnMWAwqHhuIvCpDoxS@G7jMK74biywqT//1JvY2s). You can also use a footer that doesn't pair each input with the output, and just spits them out in order: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/n4e7uRw1zjjYcWvhwR/ehJVaG3g939xza/XDHpkNL/gNlgvKTs4FUQGJBahGQDk7OLC7OLyoGMn0yqxKLUkBiBWA1cw@3P2paE/kfAA "Jelly – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 40 bytes

```javascript
s=>['Spock','Lizard','Rock'][s.length%4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvu/2NYuWj24ID85W11H3SezKrEoBcgIAvFjo4v1clLz0ksyVE1i/6flF2kUpRaX5pQo5KcpRHNxpmlAlGnqgNkQM6CcgMSC1CIYB2oqTF1yZnFxflGxuiZXrKZCcn5ecX5Oql5OfjrUdM3/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 42 bytes

```
il͍4%:0)9*?~"Spock"@1)9*?"Lizard"@"Rock"@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z8z52yviaqVgaalln2dUnBBfnK2koMhiKfkk1mVWJSi5KAUBBb8b5eYDWEaGDid7eUCcisrK5UCEgtSi1CEQKJQvWjCEDmIJdikYAqSM4uL84uKIWr@AwA)

Footer runs all five input possibilities (the `y` sequences make them print in the correct order, no I'm not sure why the last one needed so many) and presets the stack with an input value (the `i`nput command then reads no input) and a newline. Remove the footer to use input instead.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 44 bytes

```python
lambda s:["Spock","Lizard","Rock"][len(s)%4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKlopuCA/OVtJR8knsyqxKAXICALxY6NzUvM0ijVVTWL/p@UXKRQrZOYpREPkdBRgmhSUAhILUotADJh2oFxyZnFxflGxUqwVF2dBUWZeiUaxjoK6rp26jkIa0EjN/wA)

Uses the input-length-modulo-4 strategy in [Jo King's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195084/78410).

Comment: And it’s readable!

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>51</strike> 49 bytes

Thanks to Unrelated String for the suggestion.

The second byte of the string has sufficient uniqueness that I can take its two least-significant bits and use them to then index into a string (with the longest-length result at the end if I rotate the result, fortunately!) The separator between the strings should be a literal `NUL` character, but I put a space in between them below so that you can see the gaps.

```c
f(char*s){s="Spock Paper Scissors"+(s[1]-3)%4*6;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7LCsIwFERd5ysuFSFJrSiKm6hf4ELsUlyE21dQm5KkLiz99mtbcTczHIaDSYlIVHCstJNedP4YpY3Fx@yim9zNUjTeW@ejmPvb5p5sxWIn96qnuanx2WY5HHzIjF1VJ8ZMHeClTc3HoF2JSxhvQcqhvAV0DKCwjiuQcTxOSkDTBs8L/iOEGgiXh9bVsFasJ7oOKjQJ0SREZ/PRLqO/1xc)

Comment: You can replace the `\0`s with literal null bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7LCsIwFERd5ysuFSFJrSiKm6hf4ELsUlyE21dQm5KkLiz99mtbcTczHIaDSYlIVHCstJNedP4YpY3Fx@yim9zNUjTeW@ejmPvb5p5sxWIn96qnuanx2WY5HHzIjF1VJ8ZMHeClTc3HoF2JSxhvQcqhvAV0DKCwjiuQcTxOSkDTBs8L/iOEGgiXh9bVsFasJ7oOKjQJ0SREZ/PRLqO/1xc "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>73</s> 69 bytes

```python
lambda i:l[l.index(i)-1]
l="Rock Lizard Spock Scissors Paper".split()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY69DsIgFIX3PsUNE8TYREcTfAIH047qgKWNNyIQYFBfHiOgMJ7z5fzYV7gZvY0LP0clHlcpAHfqpHrUcn5SZOvNpVOcDGa6wwHfwkkY7VeME3pvnIejsLMjvbcKA2XROtQBcoDvgcAKFpokYV2BuaHSpCtOjQ3OC39cblSejab@d61ZKBZh8QM)

Since there are already plenty of ports of [@JoKing's excellent answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195084/56555), here is a different way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 43 bytes

```hs
(k!!).length
k="Spock":"Lizard":"Rock":"":k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYwxCsMwDEX3nkIRHdqhPUDAN@hQmrWLcOzE2LGFFCj08FVDMv3/4L8/k@ZQikX3tkvuuuu9hDqt8yk7HLj5jD0@0pdk3MrrYOyzLZQqOGBJdYUzLMQQt/w0GRX2Iew6PImDwHEBg0@qTRTt52OhSe3mmf8)

The mod-4 approach. Longer approaches:

```hs
f t|t<"Q"="Scissors"|t<"Sd"="Spock"|1<2="Paper"   (47)
f.last;f 'k'="Paper";f 'r'="Lizard";f _="Rock"    (46)
(["Spock","Lizard","Rock"]!!).(`mod`4).length     (45)
(words"Spock Lizard Rock"!!).(`mod`4).length      (44)
(cycle["Spock","Lizard","Rock",""]!!).length      (44)
(cycle(words"Spock Lizard Rock .")!!).length      (44)
```

Comment: Welcome back, Lynn!

Comment: I tried golfing some tweaks to your code, but it looks like your alternatives have pretty much covered everything. I did get two kind-of weird 45's: [1](https://tio.run/##Ncy9CsIwFIbhW/kaOuhgpq69Awexq8shfw1Nk0NOQfDijSXg9E7Pu5JsLqXm51e7vEu1ojTu8UPV4lnMBo2Fz6phuOpgLCadXA7H2naKGTO4xnxgxE4Mf7Y/oLrtEg9iV//PxUSRUkW1r/GJgrSbYf4B), [2](https://tio.run/##JYyxCsMwEEP3foUwXdsPKPgPOpRm7XI4cXrYiY@7QCEfH8e4IPQ0SPqSpSnnGv2nRtvumZrtLEiX5N2Td9LRPdy7hNTQNEiPqS7EKzxEed1wxUKC2PgrOhr6AL2LF8mk@F9hCGxW1Fw9Qsw0W70FkRM).

Answer (score 3):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 1359 bytes

(Whitespace added for readability)

```
R.Ajax,.Puck,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Puck]Ajax:
Open mind.Open mind.You is the remainder of the quotient betweenyou a big big cat.
Be you nicer a cat?If solet usScene V.
Be you nicer I?If solet usScene X.
You is twice twice twice twice the sum ofa big big cat a cat.Speak thy.You is the sum ofthe sum ofyou a big big big big cat a cat.Speak thy.You is the sum ofthe sum ofyou a big big big big cat a pig.Speak thy.You is the sum ofthe square oftwice the sum ofa big big cat a cat a cat.Speak thy.You is the sum ofyou the sum ofa cat twice twice the sum ofa big cat a cat.Let usScene L.
Scene V:.Ajax:
You is the sum ofa big cat the square ofthe sum ofa big big big cat a cat.Speak thy.You is twice twice twice twice the sum ofa big big big cat a pig.Speak thy.You is the sum ofyou a pig.Speak thy.You is the sum ofyou twice twice the sum ofa big pig a pig.Speak thy.You is the sum ofyou a big big big cat.Let usScene L.
Scene X:.Ajax:
You is the sum ofa big cat the square ofthe sum ofa big big big cat a cat.Speak thy.You is the sum ofyou a big big big big cat.Speak thy.You is the sum ofyou twice the sum ofa big cat a cat.Speak thy.You is the sum ofyou twice the sum ofa big big cat a cat.Remember you.Speak thy.Speak thy.You is the sum ofyou a big big pig.Speak thy.You is the sum ofyou the sum ofa big cat a cat.Speak thy.Recall.
Scene L:.Ajax:Speak thy.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVPBboMwDP0Vf0CVD@AyddIOSEirqFR1mnYIqdtlhUAhUdevZw6gBVbWZJO2Aygx79nPz6ap8rZN2fKNvy/Yyojjgi2Fhjhia4EK7eH5QWmswUKAqx1Y1Iu9RY8VKiik2jF3eioNyAb0K0KNBacQcct9FziZUktUGjLUZ0R1ISyHTB66R3DN7hFsUElBLG5Dd/EemjJHDabpJW2mqPgasf1UcSbI3JvENKYgXZPyfUW2rpAfCXMZN9PD3Wmq/Q@SVPLgTXIyvEZ78Xfll2XFjFNY0i3TXNJk5H0yLM4m6pYquirjyNMWZsT7HP3BdIN97UcSALpVkeihlb4InPVy@w9e@ncy0JBvt@RX9GmKFAssMvrpiTDKF9xNyFgD9KcoeJ4Pw0mG4bjPbbviFdYf)

Explanation:

I get the second character of the input mod 4:

- This is 0 when the input is `Spock`, at which point Puck is neither nicer than a cat nor nicer than Ajax. Then, Scene I prints `Paper`.
- This is 1 when the input is `Paper` or `Lizard`, at which point Puck is not nicer than a cat, but he is nicer than Ajax. Then, Scene X prints `Scissors`.
- This is 3 when the input is `Rock` or `Scissors`, at which point Puck is nicer than a cat. Then, Scene L prints `Spock`.

Possible improvements:

- Better math when printing to get between the letters, including switching characters and using `Recall` more
- Better modulus because some of the things are longer than others, and I could reuse the `ock`
- Possibly better ways to write the existing numbers. I actually am using a brute forcer that I wrote to do this, but it doesn’t yet account for getting between the letters (using ‘you’). GitHub link coming soon.

This was really fun and I love this language and I have no regrets.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>30</s> 27 bytes

```
'R(`R
Sp
'i(K`Rock
K`Lizard
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F89SCMhiCu4gEs9U8M7ISg/OZvLO8EnsyqxKOX/fzA3uABEBiQWpBZxQSS4gpMzi4vzi4oB) Link includes all possible test cases. @BusinessCat's answer works perfectly well in Retina 0.8.2 but for Retina 1 we can do a little better by using a conditional stage. Explanation:

```
'R(`
```

If the input contains `R`...

```
R
Sp
```

... then replace the `R` with `Sp`, thus turning `Rock` into `Spock`...

```
'i(
```

... otherwise if the input contains `i`...

```
K`Rock
```

... then overwrite it with the string `Rock`, which beats `Lizard` and `Scissors`...

```
K`Lizard
```

... otherwise overwrite the input with `Lizard`, which beats `Spock` and `Paper`.

Comment: Nice. I still need to learn the new features in Retina 1. The `.{6,}` is clever though and saves bytes for mine too.

Comment: @BusinessCat I'm glad it helped you, as I've switched to an even better Retina 1 method now!

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>42</s> 36 bytes

```ruby
->c{%w(Spock Lizard Rock)[c.size%4]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y65WrVcI7ggPzlbwSezKrEoRSEIyNaMTtYrzqxKVTWJrf1fUFpSrJGml5yYk6OhBJJV0tTkQhEMSCxILcIQDU7OLC7OLyrGkIBYhKm@AGL2fwA)

---

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>43</s> 39 bytes

```ruby
->c{%w(Lizard Rock Paper)[c[-1].ord%3]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y65WrVcwyezKrEoRSEoPzlbISCxILVIMzo5WtcwVi@/KEXVOLb2f0FpSbFGml5yYk6OhhJImZKmJheKIFgbhmhwcmZxcX5RMYYExEZM9QUQs/8DAA)

The second one is an alternative I found to Jo's method, using the ASCII value of the last character, but alas is 3 bytes longer in Ruby.

It is conceivable that my method is better in some language where finding the ASCII value of the last character is shorter than finding the string's length, but I don't know of any.

EDIT: Saved several bytes thanks to @IMP1

Comment: Why not `.size` instead of `.length`?

Comment: Also, have a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274703/4173627). You can use `%w(Lizard Rock Paper)` instead of `["Lizard","Rock","Paper"]`

Comment: @IMP1 Thanks for the tips, still new to Ruby.

Comment: No worries. Ruby often has multiple methods that do the same thing (like `.size` and `.length`), so it's worth looking to see if there's one that's a few characters shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>53</s> <s>49</s> 46 bytes

```fs
 ["Spock";"Lizard";"Rock"].[String.length n%4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVC9DoJADN55iobERAeJg5N/i3FjIDI4EIYLFLx4tKR3mujLI3C6ORg6td9fvrSyy4IFu4bLu0FIhGtRTcAtEqRP67AJAoMOKqBN6kRTDXvoIAvTlotbuA1j/VJS9st5uPMo86rIINXuCjRb5122O5GTZ8Ka3CEf8xqlCZTUD9gH0M@ACdq7cX1@BT5tZI5Mlg1GF9EOY00497rFT5@vNcGYqBZlivHzgCldC20ti/3H@2XPqMq5h1bdGw)

I am using the input-length-modulo-4 strategy from [Jo King's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195084/78410), so please check his answer.
And I know it's not in competition but I wanted to try something new…

Answer (score 1):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 28 bytes

```
2ORock
Lizard
SpockLÝkYHVGp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/38g/KD85m8snsyqxKIUruADIkfY5PDc70iPMveD//@DkzOLi/KJiAA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 324f 526f 636b 0d4c 697a 6172 640d 5370  2ORock.Lizard.Sp
00000010: 6f63 6b1b 4cdd 6b59 4856 4770            ock.L.kYHVGp
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 24 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
`Spock Lizd Rock`¸gUÊu4
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YFNwb2NrIExpeodkIFJvY2tguGdVynU0&input=IlJvY2si)

```
"Spock Lizard Rock" //=>compressed
.q(S) // split on " "
.g(U.l().u(4)) // return element at index ( length of input % 4 )
```

Thanks to @Shaggy for the help

Answer (score 1):

### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>69</s> <s>64</s> <s>61</s> 57 bytes

```
lambda s:[["Scissors","Paper"]['k'in s],"Rock"]['i'in s]
```

Not as short as the mod 4 solution, but not a bad alternative.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKjpaKTg5s7g4v6hYSUcpILEgtUgpNlo9Wz0zT6E4VkcpKD85GySQCRFQ@J@WX6RQrADkREPkdBSUggugDIh2IMMnsyqxKAUsBzM81oqLs6AoM69Eo1hHQV3XTl1HIU2jWFPzPwA)

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKjpaKTg5s7g4v6hYSUcpILEgtUgpNlo9Wz0zT6E4VkcpKD85GySQCRFQ@J@WX6RQrADkREPkdBSUggugDIh2IMMnsyqxKAUsBzM81oqLs6AoM69Eo1hHQV3XTl1HIU2jWFPzPwA "Python 3 – Try It Online") by deleting some spaces

Comment: Haha, thanks! First code golf, my nasty programmer habits of formatting code are still strong! I also didn't realize you could remove spaces between a string and 'in'. TIL

Comment: @Ahndwoo Check out my [tip on omitting spaces](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87181/20260). tldr: you usually need a space only when letters are followed by letters or digits.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 24 bytes

```
@c."Lzž›^ºéëEL”‡"\`lz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9weXRo//9AYy4iTHoCwp4QwptewrrDqcOrRUzClBXChyJcYGx6//9Sb2Nr)

Port of Jo King's mod-4 answer. Without the compressed string, it's 2 bytes longer: `` @c"Spock`Lizard`Rock`"\`lz ``

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 49 bytes

Mod4 approach:

```
=CHOOSE(MOD(LEN(A1),4)+1,"Spock","Lizard","Rock")
```

---

Switching on last character: 57 bytes

```
=CHOOSE(MOD(CODE(RIGHT(A1)),3)+1,"Lizard","Rock","Paper")
```

Answer (score 1):

## R, 52 bytes

```
function(x)c("Spock","Lizard","Rock")[nchar(x)%%4+1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# dotnet core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/), 47 bytes

```
h=>(new[]{"Spock","Lizard","Rock"})[h.Length%4]
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dIdzdW)

Uses the input-length-modulo-4 strategy in Jo King's answer.

Comment: You seem to be missing the function declaration part of your answer, i.e. the `public static string RPSLS(string h){return ... }` part. Taking input as a predefined variable is not an allowed input format, plus you're not actually outputting anything

Comment: This is a snippet where `h` is implicit. However, here we need a complete program or function. Unfortunately, though, dotnet core is too old to have `=>`, so a boilerplate will be quite long for this.

Comment: Fair enough. The lambda function definition is not much longer. I updated the .net fiddle to reflect that usage.

Answer (score 1):

## K, 26 bytes

```
`Paper`Rock`Lizard@&/"ki"?
```

Comment: The footer of the Jelly answer is simply a loop over the possible test cases, not a dictionary as additional argument. Jelly, and some other golfing languages like 05AB1E, have builtin dictionary files with ~10,000 words they know and can access with compressed strings. [Here is that same Jelly program without a footer, and a given argument](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef//TOG7i@KAnMWAwqHhuIvCpDoxS@G7jMK74biywqT///9Sb2Nr), so you can see the footer isn't part of the program and unrelated to the dictionary string [`“ŀ¡ḋ¤:1KỌ»`](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9qZWxsef//4oCcxYDCoeG4i8KkOjFL4buMwrv//w)

Comment: I've removed my comment, but that "program" doesn't work since it doesn't take the input as a string or as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), <s>81</s> 70 bytes

```
/~/\/\/.//.Sp/.~R/.~ock/Paper~Paper/Lizard~Lizard/Rock~Scissors/Rock/.
```

Because there is no other way to take input in ///, it goes after the `.` at the end of the code. For an input of `Spock`:

```
/~/\/\/.//.Sp/.~R/.~ock/Paper~Paper/Lizard~Lizard/Rock~Scissors/Rock/.Spock
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run////##K85JLM5ILf7/X79OPwYI9fT19YIL9PXqgoA4PzlbPyCxILWoDkzq@2RWJRal1EEo/SCgdF1wcmZxcX5RMZinr/f/PwA)

[Test suite](https://tio.run////##K85JLM5ILf7/X79OPwYI9fT19YIL9PXqgoA4PzlbPyCxILWoDkzq@2RWJRal1EEo/SCgdF1wcmZxcX5RMZinz8WlB6K5gEaAKbA2Lj2IBqAoVPH//wA)

**Explanation:**

/// works by replacing strings with other strings, within the code.

The first chunk of code, `/~/\/\/./`, works as a macro replacing `~` with `//.`. After this, the code expands to:

```
/.Sp/.//.R/.//.ock/Paper//.Paper/Lizard//.Lizard/Rock//.Scissors/Rock/
```

`/.Sp/./` and `/.R/./` change `spock` and `rock` to `ock`, allowing me to just replace `ock` with `Paper`.

The rest of the cases are just explicitly handled.

The period before the input is to make sure that none of the code itself is changed, just the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes

```python
lambda s:["Lizard","Rock","Paper"][cmp(s[-2],"e")]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKlrJJ7MqsShFSUcpKD85G0gFJBakFinFRifnFmgUR@saxeoopSppxv4vKMrMK1EAq1KwtVNQUtBWSNOAaNLkgkoGF6DKgvkIabDRSNIQq@DSEJcgyUOdhjA@ObO4OL@oGNkGqJCS5n8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 47 bytes

```
Fn.new{|s|["Spock","Lizard","Rock"][s.count%4]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BC4JAFITP@SseDwIl21PXOnbyEHkUD8u2wpK9lfc0KfW3byvhaWb4mGFGthTemqEZyMAZwpUU2XGaZa6w7Lx5Yo6F@2p@RHNfc12JMn6gfn@ql9B4TgUcQfWnOWw1wJvuLK9mG4jMOBHPgnUGU7IrP9Lbl@rYUR9nDoDHC0ZZ3yij2zaVLEuW8AM)

Uses the input-length-modulo-4 strategy in [Jo King's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195084/78410).

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

```
”‰«†ÕâŸard”#I3öè
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/q9v9Rw9xHDRsOrX7UsODw1MOLju5ILEoBiil7Gh/ednjFf53/QfnJ2VzBBSAyILEgtYjLJ7MKqIYrODmzuDi/qBgA)

Comment: Produces wrong answer for "Spock" (returns 5 "Papers" instead of the one)

Comment: @geocar [No it doesn’t](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPcRw0bDq1@1LDg8NTDi47uSCxKAYopexof3nZ4xf//wQX5ydkA).

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>36</s> <s>33</s> 31 bytes

-3 thanks to Neil

```
R
s
.{6,}
Rock
.{5}
Lizard
s
Sp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/iKuYS6/aTKeWKyg/ORvINK3l8smsSixKAUoEF/z/H5ycWVycX1QMAA)

Comment: Can the first line be `.[ci].*`?

Comment: @Neil Yeah, probably.

Comment: Or not. That makes `Rock` give `SpRock`. I guess it would need to be `^.[ci].*`

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 87 bytes

```
@set/ps=
@for %%a in (Rock.d Rock.s Paper.k Lizard.r)do @if %%~xa==.%s:~-1% echo %%~na
```

Takes input on STDIN. Works by switching on the last character of the input, which saves a case.